# What is the basis of the LDS/Mormon prohibition of facial hair for men?

Tags: lds, christian-living, culture

I have read in a few places the LDS Church has at least a general practice, if not an official teaching, that prohibits men from growing facial hair--at least for men in any position of leadership.  Apparently, Joseph Smith was "clean shaving", but many of the other prophets and leaders in times past did have significant beards and moustaches.

So, my question concerns what the basis is for this teaching and when that basis came about.  Is it an official church teaching or an unwritten policy, and is there any reason given for why facial hair, which God seems to have intended for men in some way, is inappropriate or wrong?

Comment: I may be splitting hairs here, but the church does not prohibit facial hair. The church associated universities do. As a devout member, I have only heard of this prohibition in association with church owned universities.

Comment: I am LDS and I have a beard and long hair. It’s funny how prophets of old and even the father and the son have long hair and beards but not a single general authority has one. I understand the clean shaven salesperson approach to sell the gospel to the culture, but it’s definitely not biblical or even in the other standard works of the church. I will continue to follow the example of Jesus Christ and the Father in reference to this subject which may exclude me from any church leadership or ordinance position but I don’t have a problem with that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short version: The rule is about appearing nice, clean-cut, and respectable in line with current cultural norms.  It's a matter of practicality - just look nice, in order to better represent the Church and therefore, God.

From [an address President Dallin H. Oaks gave to the 25,000 students of Brigham Young University](http://www.lds.org/new-era/1971/12/standards-of-dress-and-grooming?lang=eng).

> Unlike modesty, which is an eternal value in the sense of rightness or
>   wrongness in the eyes of God, our rules against beards and long hair
>   are contemporary and pragmatic. They are responsive to conditions and
>   attitudes in our own society at this particular point in time.
>   Historical precedents are worthless in this area. The rules are
>   subject to change, and I would be surprised if they were not changed
>   at some time in the future. But the rules are with us now, and it is
>   therefore important to understand the reasoning behind them.
>
> In the minds of most people at this time, the beard and long hair are
>   associated with protest, revolution, and rebellion against authority.
>   They are also symbols of the hippie and drug culture. Persons who wear
>   beards or long hair, whether they desire it or not, may identify
>   themselves with or emulate and honor the drug culture or the extreme
>   practices of those who have made slovenly appearance a badge of
>   protest and dissent. In addition, unkemptness—which is often (though
>   not always) associated with beards and long hair—is a mark of
>   indifference toward the best in life.

Comment: Thanks, David.  This does appear to be a bit of a cultural norm in America today.  Does this standard apply in other cultures, too, where the cultural norms are very different?

Comment: @Narnian - I need to leave for work and it'll be hours before I can come back and find actual references, but from what I remember, yes, it applies to other cultures as well, at least for missionaries.  Arguments for include that it represent the main Church's practices, and that in many countries, beards are for married men (hence the prohibition for missionaries, which are single.)  I also failed to address when the standard originated.  I'm going to guess that someone else will give a more thorough answer before I can get back, which is OK.

Comment: after taking a look at the Oaks reference, it makes me grateful not to be a Morman.  (the other "M" folks, the Mennonites, from which i come from, have had their historical issues about dress and modesty, but i think that most have gotten past it.  thank God.)

Answer (score 2):

I currently serve as a Bishop in the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints. I wore a beard before I was called to serve in this capacity. I was not required to, nor was I asked to shave. I shaved none the less as it seemed like the appropriate thing to do.

I know of only 2 instances where the male members are required to be clean shaven. As a full time Missionary for the Church and as an Ordinance worker in a Temple. It has definitely been my experience that most leaders in the Church are clean shaven, although there is no official requirement to be so, at least for Stake Leadership and local Ward Leadership. Being the norm in Leadership positions in the Church, I can only assume that being clean shaven stems from a desire to follow the example of those we believe to be Prophets and Apostles.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This doesn't really have much to do with your answer, but I find that sharing the following tends to help new visitors avoid mistaking the purpose of this site. I do hope to see more from you!  When you get a chance, please see [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)